# OpenDKIM: Add public key to domain, Debian 9, GoDaddy

Tags: opendkim

I was trying to add my DKIM public key to my domain, but i don't know how i have to modify it
This is my entire public key file

```
mail._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; "
  "p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzYi5NvkmYqFqsnjriRnJ0jUjanxZf/+mbHdTiqD0xLX6E1d2P2ncVlMNekuLe/oglYH5XdQZtG/Ru2eXOVZ6PS+c06f6rulk08Qunr0wRZ/kX7hgICLQzgUmycDmgB2G+nwKQp0K0p8yqwQsc8mVAcfE00j9Ndmm1q8fH3ojrSlRK20h/Agj9n+Cuya1e9Dvd4viCZBUV7UA2z"
  "a87N0HPAUSSEAnNtFD/er1CrOejGndFeKceyNALk3lS1WYMC4RIW0A/0VSfWYvyifWOPmIKOue1eBByshDw/b3jDmgwZaM5Ft+vmyZpjdgv9MmOWNNNfmP9aCoDcFDSgju5O1c5wIDAQAB" )  ; ----- DKIM key mail for vxempire.xyz
```

When i test it, sending an email to check-auth@verifier.port25.com, i got these results
(I'm only posting the DKIM result)

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
"iprev" check:      pass
DKIM check:         permerror
SpamAssassin check: ham

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         permerror (public key missing)
ID(s) verified:

Canonicalized Headers:
    to:<check-auth@verifier.port25.com>'0D''0A'
    subject:fsdfd'0D''0A'
    date:Tue,'20'22'20'Jan'20'2019'20'20:05:53'20'+0100'20'(CET)'0D''0A'
    from:qorg@vxempire.xyz'20'(qorg)'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=vxempire.xyz;'20's=mail;'20't=1548183953;'20'bh=3rhQvZl/qorCzillZMWP+MmcVlIsPKpHrwelGAB5i80=;'20'h=To:Subject:Date:From:Fro
+m;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    sfsdhjfhsdk'0D''0A'
    fahsdkjfhds'0D''0A'


DNS record(s):
    mail._domainkey.vxempire.xyz. 60 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa;""p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzYi5NvkmYqFqsnjriRnJ0jUjanxZf/+mbHdTiqD0xLX6E1d2P2ncVlMNekuLe/oglYH5XdQZ
+tG/Ru2eXOVZ6PS+c06f6rulk08Qunr0wRZ/kX7hgICLQzgUmycDmgB2G+nwKQp0K0p8yqwQsc8mVAcfE00j9Ndmm1q8fH3ojrSlRK20h/Agj9n+Cuya1e9Dvd4viCZBUV7UA2z""a87N0HPAUSSEAnNtFD/er1CrOejGndFeKceyNALk3lS1WYMC4RIW0
+A/0VSfWYvyifWOPmIKOue1eBByshDw/b3jDmgwZaM5Ft+vmyZpjdgv9MmOWNNNfmP9aCoDcFDSgju5O1c5wIDAQAB"

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.
```

I already search how to add the records, but i didn't find any good result

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, i had to write the entire key

```
v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzYi5NvkmYqFqsnjriRnJ0jUjanxZf/+mbHdTiqD0xLX6E1d2P2ncVlMNekuLe/oglYH5XdQZtG/Ru2eXOVZ6PS+c06f6rulk08Qunr0wRZ/kX7hgICLQzgUmycDmgB2G+nwKQp0K0p8yqwQsc8mVAcfE00j9Ndmm1q8fH3ojrSlRK20h/Agj9n+Cuya1e9Dvd4viCZBUV7UA2za87N0HPAUSSEAnNtFD/er1CrOejGndFeKceyNALk3lS1WYMC4RIW0A/0VSfWYvyifWOPmIKOue1eBByshDw/b3jDmgwZaM5Ft+vmyZpjdgv9MmOWNNNfmP9aCoDcFDSgju5O1c5wIDAQAB
```